# Преобразование данных QStringList в QVector

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Есть два массива:

1. массив точек для построения графика QVector x(N), y(N); 
   x - это данные которые берем из файла, y - вычисляется автоматически.
2. массив QStringList, в который мы читаем файл , в этом файле записаны данные в формате 1.24, 2.56, ... т.е. тип double.

Как мне преобразовать тип QStringList в QVector?

Comment: Просто проходим циклом по строкам в QStringList (i-я строка получается через метод at(i)) и каждую преобразовываем в число через метод QString  toDouble(...) и добавляем полученное число в QVector через метод push_back(...).

Comment: лучше QVector::resize а потом цикл с присваиванием

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот фрагмент кода, как из QStringList s сконвертировать все числа и сохранить в QVector v:

```
QStringList s;
QVector<double> v;

// Допустим s и v уже заполнили, например прочитали из файла.

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    bool is_ok = true;
    v.push_back(s[i].toDouble(&is_ok));
    if (!is_ok) { /* Обработать ошибку конвертации числа из строки. */ }
}
```